# Drawer body not updating after setState is called

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a controller for my screen which displays a drawer. The controller is passed in as a parameter to the home screen that displays the drawer. The drawer body should change according to the selected item.

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final HomeController controller;

  HomeScreen(this.controller);

  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => new _HomeScreenState(this.controller);
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  HomeController controller;
  TabController _tabController;

  _HomeScreenState(this.controller);

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tabController =
        TabController(length: controller.tabItems.length, vsync: this);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    switch (controller.getMenuType()) {
      case MenuType.drawer:
        return buildDrawer();
      case MenuType.tabbarbottom:
        return buildTopTabbar();
      case MenuType.tabbartop:
        return buildTopTabbar();
      default:
        return buildDrawer();
    }
  }

  Widget buildDrawer() {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("test")),
      body: _buildDrawerBody(),
      drawer: Drawer(
        child: ListView(padding: EdgeInsets.zero, children: _getDrawerTiles()),
      ),
    );
  }
```

The user chooses a configuration to show a tabbar or a drawer. In the case of the drawer, the problem is that even after setState is called and the drawerbody function is creating a new widget Pagebuilder with the correct page, however it is not reflected(or refreshed) on the screen

```
Widget _buildDrawerBody() {
    Page page = controller.getSelectedPage();
    PageBuilderController pageController = PageBuilderController(page: page);
    return PageBuilder(pageController);
  }

  List<Widget> _getDrawerTiles() {
    Widget header = DrawerHeader(
      child: Text('Drawer Header'),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.blue,
      ),
    );
    List<Widget> tiles = controller.tabItems
        .map<Widget>((tab) => ListTile(
              title: Text(tab.label),
              onTap: () {
                // Update the state of the app
                // ...
                setState(() {
                  controller.selectedTab = tab;
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                });
              },
            ))
        .toList(growable: true);
    tiles.insert(0, header);
    return tiles;
  }
```

I have made sure that getselectedpage returns the correct result

Comment: A little side note: Your `State` implementations should have parameterless constructors. To access the final fields of the widget from the `State`, use the `widget` property. E.g. `widget.controller.tabItems.length`

Comment: Can you create a minimal, complete, runnable example? It's hard to understand the partial code above without seeing the source of `HomeController`.

Answer (score 0):

What I've encountered is that widgets don't work as expected when you put them in methods outside the build method. Try declaring buildDrawer and _buildDrawerBody as final Widgets inside the build method, and see if that makes a difference.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  final Widget _buildDrawerBody = ...

  final Widget buildDrawer = Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(title: Text("test")),
    body: _buildDrawerBody,
    drawer: Drawer(
      child: ListView(padding: EdgeInsets.zero, children: _getDrawerTiles()),
    ),
  );

  switch (controller.getMenuType()) {
    case MenuType.drawer:
      return buildDrawer;
    case MenuType.tabbarbottom:
      return buildTopTabbar();
    case MenuType.tabbartop:
      return buildTopTabbar();
    default:
      return buildDrawer;
  }
}
```

This article might provide some insight on best practice in creating widgets: https://medium.com/flutter-io/out-of-depth-with-flutter-f683c29305a8